# Getting a web service provider for location in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an app in which I am giving the user an option of saving his Geo location.

I have codes for getting his location co-ordinates, now the next step is to find a web service to get me a location for the specific co-ordinates. The video tutorial uses a http://msrmaps.com/TerraService2.asmx web service for giving it the location.

I tried searching but am not able to get any such web service provider. Please help. The site referred to is now down

could u refer another site or another method for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that what you want to do is a Reverse Gocode. That is, get the address from geocoordinates.

You have different options for this. For example following ones:

1. [Bing Map services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx): offers both [SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966763.aspx) and [REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx) interfaces.
2. [Nokia's HERE Maps](http://developer.here.com/) services, which offer a REST interface. You can get the address with a [single http query](http://developer.here.com/places#_48_INSTANCE_1FN2Ea4jadS4_=http://developer.here.com/docs/places/index.html?).
3. [Google's Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding). It also allows you to reverse geocoding using REST.

Answer (score 0):

[Bing maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966828.aspx) is quite easy to use. Just sign up for a developer key [here](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx).

You can also google around for "reverse geocoding api".

Answer (score 0):

If using the Bing Maps REST services in WP you may find this documentation on how to use the service in .NET useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx